# Blender Spreadsheet Not Generating Data in Geometry Node

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am creating a basic geometry node and it was first creating the x,y,z values of the Line in the spreadsheet as show below.

[image]

However, when I pointed the geometry node to a Point instance the x, y, z values are disappearing.. why is this so?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I got it.. instead of selecting the line i should be selecting the main object of my point instance which was the circle on top